# Get UID and insert in object in database firebase Angular 6

Tags: firebase, angular6

I need to get UID that user created in Authentication and insert this UID in item created in Database Firebase, firt I create user in my auth.ts

```
createUser(user: any, path: string) {
return this.afu.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
                            .then((res) => { 
                              let id = res.uid;
                              this.teste(id, path);
                              return this.service.save(user, path)
                            });
}
```

in this service I'll send to another service to create one object relationship him now my userService.ts, so how to get this UID and insert in user/id atribute?

```
save(user: any, path: string) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return this.db.list(this.PATH + path)
            .push(user)
            .then(() => resolve())
   })
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I hope I did not understand your question wrong.

Like mentioned here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var name, email, photoUrl, uid, emailVerified;

    if (user != null) {
      name = user.displayName;
      email = user.email;
      photoUrl = user.photoURL;
      emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
      uid = user.uid; 
    }
```

Now you got your current user's id.

now insert it to your table:

```
ref.child("something"+count).set({
  uid: this.uid,
  email: this.email,
  //and more
});
```

count stands for the id of the object for example:

```
{
  "0": {
      "uid": "22",
      "email": "something@gmail.com"
    },
   "1": {
      "date_of_birth": "33",
      "full_name": "anothersomething@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

is your corresponding json file when you ask for something table.

Comment: so, whats better way to do this ? I can add the UID created in Authentication in Key object in Database ? if no, I can add UID in atribute ID in object Database ? I adedd a picture bellow above...

Comment: note, in this case I am a administrator and I am added someone user ok

Comment: Of course, you can add that UID but instead you can generate the another ID such as in sign up you can get the length of your table (that is, size of your table) and use that as id. For example, for first user id is 0 because table has no instance, for second user id is 1 because only 1 instance is in your table, and so on, It would be much more easy to implement and use.

Comment: I did is in my code   createUser( user: any, path: string): Promise<any> {
    return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    .then( newUser => {
      firebase.database()
      .ref(`/users/${path}/`)
      .child(newUser.uid)
      .set(user);
    });
  }

Answer (score 0):

I did so in my code with base in your code friend and work to me thanks friend

```
createUser( user: any, path: string): Promise<any> {
return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
  .then( newUser => {
    firebase.database()
    .ref(`/users/${path}/`)
    .child(newUser.uid)
    .set(user);
  });
}
```